# Wordpress - Access php variables from another file within an html file

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a page with several tabs and to keep things organized I have one file for the overall page template and one for each tab that will be opened. When pressing the tabs I hide/unhide (with the class hidden which sets display: none) sections which is originally placed like this in my `page_template.php` file:

```
<div id="content-wrapper">
    <section id="page_tab_1">
        <?php get_template_part( 'page/page_tab_1' ); ?>
    </section>
    <section id="page_tab_2" class="hidden">
        <?php get_template_part( 'page/page_tab_2' ); ?>
    </section>
</div>
```

Now I want to use a variable in both `page_template.php` and `page_tab_1.php`. When placing `$my_variable = 'Test';` at the top of the `page_template.php` I can of course use it below with e.g. `<?php echo $my_variable; ?>`, but when I try to echo it in `page_tab_1.php` it doesn't work.

I solved it by adding functions at the top of `page_template.php` like this:

```
function get_my_variable(){return 'Test';}
```

Then I can use the following code in both files:

```
$my_variable = get_my_variable();
```

The reason I don't want to put `$my_variable = 'Test';` in both files is because some of the real variables take some calculations and I don't want to duplicate too much code.

**Question**

I thought I could just declare the variables at the top of `page_template.php` since the other code is pasted below that, but I guess that is not how `get_template_part` works. So is there a more elegant/smart way to declare variables in `page_template.php` which can then be used by all `page_tab_x.php` files?

Comment: Did you consider using the SESSION?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I don't know what that is.

Comment: Then you probably should not be playing with WordPress coding yet

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I have a working website with 1000s of customers with a WP theme I built much on my own. Comments like that won't help me with my issue, so if you know an answer to my question then please explain it and then use the "Post Your Answer" button below.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php or https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-sessions/

Comment: You could also declare your variable as a [global](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) one, however know that that's generally considered a bad coding practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_template_part` let you pass additional arguments to the template through the third parameter `$args`.

@see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

```php
get_template_part(
    'template-part',
    'name',
    array(
        'key1'  => $myValue1,
        'key2'  => 'myValue2',
    )
);
```

Comment: Oh, forgot about this one. _This is the way_.

Comment: The link amarinediary shared explains that part as well, @eligolf

Comment: @cabrerahector, I tried what is said in the document by adding the argument "array('key1'  => "test")" and then tried to use $args['key1'] but it outputs nothing. Am I missing something?

Comment: That's odd. Which WordPress version are you using over there? __Edit:__ Wait, the third argument needs to be an _array_ (as seen on the example above). Are you passing a _string_ to it?

Comment: @cabrerahector, I am stupid, the previous developer had a middle function which called get_template_part with only 2 arguments. When I call it myself directly with 3 arguments it works perfectly. Sorry for being stupid and thank you for the help!

Comment: No worries, and thank @amarinediary instead. I just provided some minor guidance :P